# L1 and Ln cache: when are they written?

Tags: cpu-cache

I have been following the "[High Performance Computer Architecture](https://eu.udacity.com/course/high-performance-computer-architecture--ud007)" course from Georgia Tech (also on YouTube), and unless I've missed something, I cannot see where the following has been explained:

If I have a multilevel cache, L1/L2/L3/Ln:

1) what decides what level of this hierarchy a block fetched from memory initially gets put in?

2) If I evict a block from L1, does that mean it gets moved to L2 (replacing a block from L2 depending on the replacement policy), and so forth for L2 to L3, and L3 to Ln, until the block evicted from the last level cache gets written to memory?

**PS** And yes, I have searched for this, so don't downvote assuming I haven't :)

**Update**

After the answer given below, I went back to the video course and found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8DQG9Pvp3U&feature=youtu.be&t=1m17s).  It seems to suggest that data is **initially fetched into the L2 cache**, then "fed" to the L1 cache.  This also shows how, *without the inclusion bit set*, L1 and L2 can become "out of sync".

3) Is this generally what happens in all caches?  IE if I have a 7 layer cache, will the block be fetched into L7, then fed L7->L6, L6->L5 ... and finally L2->L1?  This seems like a lot of work...

4) Except in the situation shown in the linked video (if the caches get "out of sync" then certain data will only be available in one cache even though it started out in both caches), it seems that having the same data in multiple levels of the cache all the time (i.e. when the inclusion bit is set) is a waste; we have to copy it amongst all the levels.  This can't be the case though, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Usually any accessed data are saved into L1, independent whether they were previously available in L1, L2... or memory only.

For exclusive cache, data are stored ONLY in L1, for inclusive one, in the entire hierarchy. There are also mixed strategies. Also, some CPUs have "victim cache", which is extra cache level which gets ONLY data moved out of LLC (last level cache).

2) Yes, for write-back exclusive cache.

3) You misunderstood his explanation. He said that data are fetched and placed to both caches. Inclusion, btw, isn't the "bit set", but entire cache policy. The policy is built right into the hardware.

4) Exclusive cache better use precious space, but each time you have to bring new block into L1, you have to displace some block to L2, then some one to L3... and finally some one to memory. This means a lot of work. With inclusive cache, you just drop data from L1 cache, or replace older copy in L2 with newer copy displaced from L1.

As result, exclusive strategy is more optimal when adjacent cache levels has closer sizes (f.e. <=4x) and inclusive is better when sizes are very different.

More info at [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_inclusion_policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_inclusion_policy)

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I have updated the original question after reviewing your comment and using it to search the course I linked to: could you please check my update and update your answer?  Thanks!

Comment: @Wad done......

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to edit your answer.  I don't understand 3) and 4) however, sorry.  3) So in an N level cache, what level is written to **first** when we have a miss?  Is it N?  And if so, is that same block copied to all higher levels?  4) Regarding exclusive, why do you need to displace from L1 to L2? Is this what I questioned in 2) above that you answered?  Inclusion: surely **this** involves the most work, copying a block across all N caches??

Comment: @Wad 3) Data are written into all cache levels simultaneously. It can be done since all hardware in the CPU can work simultaneously. Physically, it can be done earlier or later. What is really important for us is that data become available for following operations so next access to A will be done at L1 speed. (Of course, in exclusive cache data are written only into L1)

Comment: 4) In exclusive cache, when you displace data from L1, they absent in L2. So you should save them there for the case they will be used again (and it's the only way anything can be written to L2 when caches are exclusive)

Comment: 4) Copying data read from memory into all cache levels is indeed more work compared to L1-only writing, but this situation is much less frequent than moving data back and forth between cache levels. Just take into account that in more than 90% cases when data are missing from L1, they are still in L2 or L3.

Comment: Thanks again for helping me.1) OK, so lets say I have an N layer inclusive cache; the course I linked to states that this means a block **must be present in all layers of the cache**. So what is the point of having N layers if they all hold the same data? 2) You said *In exclusive cache, when you displace data from L1,they absent in L2*. Are you saying that if we replace a block in L1, we then move it to L2? *It's the only way anything can be written to L2 when caches are exclusive* -so this is how an Lx cache gets populated -when data is removed from L(x-1)?And this is only true in EX caches?

Comment: 1) in inclusive cache, L(n-1) info should present in L(n) too, but not vice versa (exactly because L(n) is larger than L(n-1)). 2) Yes. Inclusive cache immediately writes new data to all levels, in exclusive cache new data starts at L1 and then swapped out to higher levels until it finally swapped out to memory. More info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_inclusion_policy

Comment: Excellent; the wikipedia article really soildified my understanding.  If you could, please put the link at the end of your answer as it is quite buried down here, and will no doubt help others.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Bulat, I hope you don't mind but since you clearly know what you are talking about on this subject, could you possibly comment on https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/108863/compiler-instructions-to-sync-core-caches-are-they-really-needed?  Thank you.  @Bulat